# Print a Z shape pyramid using * stars

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that outputs a Z pattern that is `n` number of `*` across the top, bottom, and connecting line using for loops.

Example:

```
Enter a number: 6

******
    *
   *
  *
 *
******
```

This is my current code, it's producing a half pyramid upside down.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ZShape {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
      int n = input.nextInt(); 

      for (int x = 0; x <= n; x++) {
         for (int y = n; y >= 1; y--) {
            if (y > x) {
               System.out.print("* ");
            }
            else
               System.out.print(" ");
         } 
         System.out.println(); 
      }      
   }
}
```

Comment: What result is your current code producing?

Comment: It's producing a half triangle upside down.

Comment: Edit your question with this information. Myself, I'd use 4 for loops, one to print the first row, two for loops with one nested in the other to print the diagonal, and one to print the last row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the logic in the following code:

- Loop over each row of the output (so from 0 to `n` excluded so that we have `n` rows)
- Loop over each column of the output (so from 0 to `n` excluded so that we have `n` columns)
- We need to print a `*` only when it is the first row (`x == 0`) or the last row (`x == n - 1`) or the column is in the opposite diagonal (`column == n - 1 - row`)

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < n; column++) {
            if (row == 0 || row == n - 1 || column == n - 1 - row) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Sample output for `n = 6`:

```
******
    * 
   *  
  *   
 *    
******
```

(Note that this output has trailing white-spaces for each row, you did not specify whether they should be included, but it is easy to remove them by adding another check).

Comment: Thanks! Also thanks for the great explanation, this will really help.

Answer (score 1):

How about using three loops instead?

```
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
for (int x = n-3; x >= 0; x--) {
    for (int y = x; y >= 0; y--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("*");
}
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Star {
public static void main(String[] args) {

      for (int i = 0; i <=4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <=4; j++) 
            {
                if (i==4 ||   (i+j)==4 || i==0) 
                {
                    System.out.print(" * ");
                } 
                else 
                {
                    System.out.print("    ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a logic to print Z shape:

1. when `i = 1`, then the First line will print only "#"
2. when `i = n`, then the Last line will print in same way by "#" only
3. when `i = j`, that means it will execute one diagonal line by "#" only

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int n = scr.nextInt();
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(int j = n; j >= 1; j--) {
            
            if (i == 1 || i == n || i == j) {
                System.out.print("# ");
            }
            
            else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j,n=5;
        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            for(j = 1; j <= n ; j++){
                if(i==1 || i+j == n+1 || i==n)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).